# Act like a bluetooth midi module

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, midi

Basically I would like to investigate if it is possible to connect a digital stage piano (Yamaha P45 - if that matters) via usb to the pi and make it (the pi) act like a bluetooth 'bridge' (for lack of a better term), in order to wirelessly connect (the piano) to Mac / iDevices (Garageband for example supports bluetooth midi devices in all platforms).

I have done some research in the web (and will continue to do so, updating this post with any findings), but I guess it would be helpful if anybody has any experience or advices in the subject.

Finally, as a reference, [here is a commercial adapter](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/accessories/interfaces/ud-bt01/?mode=model) that is designed for this purpose

Comment: Why do you need your piano to act as some Bluetooth middle man? Surely there are dedicated devices for this sort of thing?

Comment: This appears to be [work in progress](http://blog.felipetonello.com/2015/12/14/midi-over-bluetooth-low-energy-on-linux/).

Comment: @DarthVader I have edited the question to be more clear on what I am trying to achieve. I guess a super short description of the question could be: "Can I make the pi act like a usb to bluetooth midi adapter?". Thanks for your input btw!

Comment: Most likely it is *possible* but, most likely it would required a lot of (skilled) labour unless you can find someone who's already done it and released the project publicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same plan.  But first, I just want to make a small affordable MIDI synthesizer.  The best answers I've found so far (but have not yet tried):

1. Add a MIDI input interface to your PI.  There are many good explanations of this. I liked this one:
   http://www.samplerbox.org/article/midiinwithrpi
2. Check out: http://www.fluidsynth.org/ which is an open source MIDI/audio ecosystem with dozens of incredible apps.  All you would have to do is build their basic software and run it from the command line, specifying one of their sound font files.

If the above works, I plan on using a pair of BlueTooth modules from Microchip.  I'll configure them to work as serial port relays at 31.25 kbaud (1 Mhz / 16).  The modules run off 3.3V, but most MIDI *basically uses 5V*, so we take some power from a MIDI OUT, and use it to pump a capacitor and regulate that down to 3.3V to power the BT module.  This must be how the Yamaha device works.  If you only wanted to go in one direction (from your keyboard to your PI) then you could make a device that only plugged into your keyboard's MIDI OUT and you could power it with a battery or wall wart.

So if that works, I will have a generic BT MIDI "wireless cable".  From there, I would explore the BT on the PI and try to use it instead of my device.

And, you probably know, Apple is way ahead of everybody when it comes to BT and MIDI.  If anyone knows how to buy one of their evaluation boards without being a seriously company and qualifying for their elite club, please advise.

With time, I will hack and reverse engineer everything Apple does with BT.  I will try to abide by all of their rules, even if I can't get a copy of them.

Comment: Awesome. Much more than what I asked for. Thanks a lot Bill :)